# Sudden "Error establishing database connection" Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm working and out of no where i get this error.  Didn't upload anything.  I get `Error establishing a database connection`.  The only thing i've done recently is install piwik analytics but i tested that thoroughly on the test server.  I'm scared that i've corrupted the database.  And i haven't got the most recent backup.  I can't access any page on the website.. front end or backend.  What is going on?  Is the database overloaded?.. if so when does it reboot, all i want is the website to work as it doesn't belong to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should have to refer [this](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-error-establishing-a-database-connection-in-wordpress/) link.hope you may got your solution from there.

It could be that your database login credentials are wrong or have been changed.

It could be that your database server is unresponsive.

It could be that your database has been corrupted.

Try to define `define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);` in`wp-config.php` file.
then visit this link http://www.yoursite.com/wp-admin/maint/repair.php.
you see database repair option.

Comment: Thanks!! i had to change localhost to IP address and suddenly worked again.

Comment: glad that my answer helps you.